# Cannot delete multiple items on react using firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to delete multiple items on click of checkbox using firestore. But, onSnapshot method of firestore is causing issue with the state.

After running the code I can click on checkbox and delete the items, the items get deleted too but I get an error page, `"TyperError: this.setState is not a function"` in onCollectionUpdate method.

After refreshing the page I can see the items deleted.

Here's my code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.ref = firebase.firestore().collection('laptops');
        this.unsubscribe = null;
        this.state = { laptops: [], checkedBoxes: [] };
        this.toggleCheckbox = this.toggleCheckbox.bind(this);
        this.deleteProducts = this.deleteProducts.bind(this);
    }
    toggleCheckbox = (e, laptop) => {
        if (e.target.checked) {
            let arr = this.state.checkedBoxes;
            arr.push(laptop.key);
            this.setState = { checkedBoxes: arr };
        } else {
            let items = this.state.checkedBoxes.splice(this.state.checkedBoxes.indexOf(laptop.key), 1);
            this.setState = {
                checkedBoxes: items
            }
        }
    }

    deleteProducts = () => {
        const ids = this.state.checkedBoxes;
        ids.forEach((id) => {
            const delRef = firebase.firestore().collection('laptops').doc(id);
            delRef.delete()
                .then(() => { console.log("deleted a laptop") })
                .catch(err => console.log("There is some error in updating!"));
        })
    }

    onCollectionUpdate = (querySnapshot) => {
        const laptops = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            const { name, price, specifications, image } = doc.data();
            laptops.push({
                key: doc.id,
                name,
                price,
                specifications,
                image
            });
        });
        this.setState({ laptops });
        console.log(laptops)
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.unsubscribe = this.ref.onSnapshot(this.onCollectionUpdate);
    }

    getLaptops = () => {
        const foundLaptops = this.state.laptops.map((laptop) => {
            return (
                <div key={laptop.key}>
                        <Container>
                            <Card>
                                <input type="checkbox" className="selectsingle" value="{laptop.key}" checked={this.state.checkedBoxes.find((p) => p.key === laptop.key)} onChange={(e) => this.toggleCheckbox(e, laptop)} />
                                ...carddata
                            </Card>
                        </Container>
                </div>
            );
        });
        return foundLaptops;
    }

    render = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                <button type="button" onClick={this.deleteProducts}>Delete Selected Product(s)</button>
                <div className="row">
                    {this.getLaptops()}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably just forgot to `bind` the `onCollectionUpdate` so `this` referes not where you expectit to refer to.

Can you pls also change the `this.setState` bug you have there as @David mentioned also:

```js
 toggleCheckbox = (e, laptop) => {
        if (e.target.checked) {
            let arr = this.state.checkedBoxes;
            arr.push(laptop.key);
            this.setState({ checkedBoxes: arr });
        } else {
            let items = this.state.checkedBoxes.splice(this.state.checkedBoxes.indexOf(laptop.key), 1);
            this.setState({
                checkedBoxes: items
            })
        }
    }
```

If you already did that pls update your question with the latest code.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Can you pls follow the instructions there.

Answer (score 0):

In the toggleCheckbox function you set the this.setState to a object.
You will need to replace that with this.setState({ checkedBoxes: items})

So you use the function instead of setting it to a object

Comment: I tried this, still getting the same error.